Repeating Similar If Statements, Need Help Optimizing. (Unity 2D)
I'm new to unity and am working on a platformer game for my first game jam. In the game manager I need to set the 'current level' variable to the current level.
[SerializeFeild] private int level;

private GameObject currentLevel;

[Header("Levels")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject level1;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level2;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level3;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level4;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level5;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level6;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level7;
[SerializeField] private GameObject level8;

private void SetCurrentLevel()
{
    if(level == 1)
    {
        currentLevel == level1;
    }
    else if (level == 2)
    {
        currentLevel == level2;
    }
    else if (level == 3)
    {
        currentLevel == level3;
    }
    else if (level == 4)
    {
        currentLevel == level4;
    }
    else if (level == 5)
    {
        currentLevel == level5;
    }
    else if (level == 6)
    {
        currentLevel == level6;
    }
    else if (level == 7)
    {
        currentLevel == level7;
    }
    else if (level == 8)
    {
        currentLevel == level8;
    }
}

I'm sure there is an easy or faster way  to do this but I can't find any thing online to help me solve this issues. Any ideas?

well, you could use a switch statement, you could have an array, and then you could just do currentlevel = levels[level] ...

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/arrays-9o

I thought you might like to be able to set that level using the function since you have it set to private.
[SerializeFeild] private int level;

private GameObject currentLevel;

[Header("Levels")]
[SerializeField] private List<GameObject> levelObjects = new List<GameObjects>();

private void SetCurrentLevel(int _level)
{
    level = _level;
    currentLevel = levelObjects[level-1];
}


Yes, in most cases when you have more than 2 similar things, you usually want to use an array. Especially when you plan to use an index on them.
